# Incremental Learning in Yolo or in general

Tags: computer-vision, yolo

I'm a little lost and I ask for a little help because I don't know how to go on.

Let's say I have 10000 images where I have a cat and dog in each.

Can I leave the same set of images to two different people where one makes dog and one cat labels? Then train the N. net first to recognize all the dogs and then to recognize all the cats?

I'm afraid the answer will be no. At least not directly. It would be transfer learning - wouldn't it?

I guess I should also have the dogs and cats marked in their classes and train all at once.

If so. Let's imagine that I have already trained the network to recognize dogs and cats and it works.

Now I want to add the recognition of elephants. Here the answer is transfer learning? or I just keep training model adding one more class?

OK, but regardless of the answer if in the new 10000 images with elephant but next to it I also have a dog or cat in the same image - I can leave them without label or that will cause the network to be confused (because in this case it will detect the cat or dog, but as there is no label in return information will be that the detection of dog or cat is not correct).

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

If your images contain cats and dogs and if you want your model to detect both of them, then training on dogs alone and then training on cats alone will confuse your model. Either train with pictures of dogs/cats alone or label both of them if they are in the same image. Same is the case with elephants.

But if you have a well-trained model already, then you can use it to generate labels for new images and manually label only those which the model missed. This will make your data collection process easier.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but I was having a similar issue when I stumbled upon this paper:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.00781.pdf

It's a paper called **"RILOD: Near Real-Time Incremental Learning for Object Detection at the Edge"**.
As far as I've read it (I confess I didn't have time to read it completely), as the title suggests, it's a technique for implementing incremental learning for real-time object detection.

Perhaps, it's useful for your needs if you are still having trouble with it, or in case anyone (like me) googles this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think you put the wrong hyperlink. Would you please kindly check?